# Looking for a self-explanatory name for RAII-object lifetime management classes

Tags: naming, raii

Lets say, I have a class named `Texture` that realizes the RAII-idiom. Furthermore I have a corresponding `TextureManager` class, that instantiates and deletes `Texture` objects. Its a 1-to-1 relationship: Each `TextureManager` instance creates one particular `Texture` object when it is time to do so and it deletes it when it is not required any more. The `TextureManager` decides this.

The point is that I'm not happy with the name of the `TextureManager` class. I think it is too vacuous, for two reasons:

1. The name `TextureManager` does not reflect the 1-to-1 relationship of a `TextureManager` object and the `Texture` object it creates/deletes.
2. The name is misleading. It could be understood as a class that loads textures from hard drive.

I've thought of a few alternatives, that I'm not happy with either:

- `TextureControl` does reflect the 1-to-1 relationship in my opinion, but it sounds more like the name of class that actually controls *existing* instances.
- `TextureLifetimeControl` would be self-explanatory, but it is long and inelegant in my opinion.
- `TextureHolder` does reflect the "possessing" nature of the the 1-to-1 relashionship, but it sounds more like an object that takes an existing instance and keeps it to me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use "Texture" instead of "TextureManager" and "TextureData" instead of "Texture". So the user manipulates a texture without knowing it is actually a manager containing a texture. I don't know if what I mean is clear...

Comment: @lodo Intresting Idea. I'm not happy with `TextureData` because this sounds more like the source of a texture to me, but maybe `TextureObject` would be an option.